# Does EU citizen have to meet financial requirement for non-EEA spouse?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, eu-citizens, family

I am an EU citizen working in Britain, self-employed, and I would like to bring my Asian wife here in a couple of months time in 2018.  Will the status of "qualified person" help me to do it?

Do I have to have a minimum income of £18,600 in order to bring her on an EEA family permit?

Comment: Thank you.... by the way, does adequate accomodation need to be prepared before my wife comes? I read somewhere, this does not apply for EEA national sponsors...

Comment: If you have a new question, please post out as a new question.

Answer (score 3):

> Will the status of "qualified person" help me to do it?

Yes.

> Do I have to have a minimum income of £18,600 in order to bring her on an EEA family permit?

No.  All you need to show is that you are self employed.  See https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/documents-you-must-provide:

> You must show that your EEA family member has a permanent right of residence or is one of the following if they’ve been in the UK for more than 3 months:
>
> - working, for example an employment contract, wage slips or a letter from an employer
> - self-employed (for example contracts, invoices or audited accounts with bank statements) and paying tax and National Insurance
> - studying, for example a letter from the school, college or university
>   financially independent, for example bank statements